# Compilation error at time of Archiving

Tags: ios, swift, the-amazing-audio-engine

I have integrated TheAmazingAudioEngine. The App is running successfully on the simulator and on the device. However, when I try to Archive it, getting following compilation error.

**'TheAmazingAudioEngine/AEBufferStack.h' file not found**

This file is present and app is running in debug mode.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: check in bundle phase in your project setting, see this file is there ?

Comment: Yes, the file is there. Able to run the app on a simulator and on a device. The issue is only for an archive.

Comment: can you paste complete error log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this troubleshooting steps.This issue appear because of search path.

1. Select your [projectName] in Xcode TARGETS.
2. Go to Build Settings tab.
3. Search "Header Search Paths"
4. Double click and add this path to both "Debug" and "Release": $(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include
   Now clean the Project and restart Xcode.
5. now you able to archive try it :)

Comment: Thanks, Shauket, it's worked. But I found a solution from here :). But your answer is correct so marked as accepted. https://github.com/TheAmazingAudioEngine/TheAmazingAudioEngine2/issues/9